# Php mailer Email message Blocked

Tags: php, email, web, gmail, phpmailer

i am using php mailer to send emails for my website the code is working very fine mails are sent properly but as soon as i try to include the verification link of my website the email message gets blocked by gmail service so the issue is i am not able to include the link in my email message please help me out of this .

> Message blocked
> Your message to saddique116p@gmail.com has been blocked. See technical details below for more information.

```
$msg = "Thank you for Registering to our website";
              $msg.="<html>Welcome<h4> $fname $lname <h4>
                 Thank You please click this link to verify your Account.
                
                <a href='http://codinginn.000webhostapp.com/verify_email.php?code=$activationcode'>click here</a>
                </html>";
```

The code above is my email body please let know how should i improve this?

Comment: What did the `technical details` say?

Comment: Does it work if you replace the host name of the link URL with something else? They might simply be blocking this based on that it points to a free hosting platform (which are often used by spammers.)

Comment: technical details say: Your message text or links look suspicious.

Comment: thanks a lot @user3783243 for the reply yes this was the issue it did worked for facebook.com